# Meaning of "it's long past time to ..."

Tags: sentence-patterns, expressions

Saw a lot of such sentences (examples below). What does the "it's long past time to..." mean?

Example:
It's long past time to ditch the use of the ubiquitous bulleted-list templates found in both Powerpoint and Keynote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another common way of saying this is with the word overdue. In your example:

```
 Ditching the use of the ubiquitous bulleted-list templates found in both Powerpoint and Keynote is an overdue change.
```

Basically it means it should have happened already ... the sooner it happens the better ... there shouldn't be anything holding us back.

Answer (score 2):

That refers to something that should have been done a long time ago. Another way of saying your example would be:

> The ubiquitous bulleted-list templates found in both Powerpoint and Keynote should have been ditched a long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

Think of ***"It is time to ditch the use of..."***
Which is much like ***"Now is the time to..."***

From there it's a simple step to see
***"It's past time to.."***

And another simple step and you've got...
***"It's long past time to.."***

Does that help?  It kind of stubs the brain until you sit down and sort it out.

Comment: Whats the downvoting about?  Seems like a pretty clear explanation to me.